# AngularJs $httpbackend.whenPOST regular expression not working

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular-ui-router, angular-mock

am getting an error
`Error: Unexpected request: POST data/employee/1
No more request expected`

Am using `angular-mocks`, `angular-ui-route` in my `app.config` i've got my `$stateProvider` routes and my mocks the main one with the issue being the one below:

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST(/data\/employee\/(\d+)/, {}, {},['id']).respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params){

        console.log('Received these data:', method, url, data, headers, params);

        return [200, {}, {}]
});
```

Calling via controller:

```
app.controller("employeeController", ['$scope','$http', "$state", "$stateParams", function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams){

   $http.post("data/employee/1").then(function(response){


   })
 })
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the mock `$httpBackend.whenPOST(url, [data], [headers], [keys])` to work optional parameters `data` and `header` need to be declared as `undefined` where they are not used and not just as empty objects `{}`.